# Problem with visualizing topics with pyLDAvis

Tags: memory, visualization, lda, topic-modeling, pyldavis

I have a problem by running this code and cant get a visualisation from the topics and words from the LDA model. Anyone who knows how to solve this problem.  I get the following warning

`"TerminatedWorkerError                     Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [168], in <cell line: 1>() ----> 1 vis_data = gensimvis.prepare(onderwerpen, corpus, id2word) pyLDAvis.display(vis_data)"`

TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

Anyone who can solve this problem?